# Java HttpURLConnection 400 Error

Tags: jsp, curl, httpurlconnection

I am trying to setup a CURL like request with JSP and am getting a 400 error and not sure what the problem is. I have read around and can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this code:

```
BASE64Encoder encoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
String inputLine;
String urlStr = "https://www.example.com/v1/Enroll/123456";
String key = "someusername0123456";
String qStr = "score=90&pass_fail=false&status=Completed";
String encodedKey = encoder.encodeBuffer(key.getBytes());
encodedKey = encodedKey.replaceAll("\n", ""); 
byte[] postData = qStr.getBytes("UTF-8");
URL url = new URL(urlStr);

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encodedKey);
con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
con.getOutputStream().write(postData);

try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(inputLine);
    }
    reader.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

The response code is 400 and response message is Bad Request. I have tried many variations of the above code found around, but nothing has worked. I don't have control over the server sending to, but this CURL command works:

```
curl -X PUT https://www.example.com/v1/Enroll/123456 -u someusername0123456: -d "score=90" -d "pass_fail=false" -d "status=Completed"
```

Comment: You have declared the `encoder` after doing the `encoder.encodeBuffer` operation?? Also remove the `content-length` header from your code and then try again.

Comment: Oops sorry, fixed that. Was making it look clean. In my actual code, its before. I have fixed that. Removing the content-length doesn't do anything. I had that in there because I was using POST at first, but getting an error that needed that.

Comment: Turns out it was on the receiving side, so this code works.